# Methods with @available(iOS 9.0, *) gets executed on 8.x

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing

I wrote unit test. Some method is marked that supports only iOS 9v.
But some methods marked with @available(iOS 9.0, *) gets executed on device which have iOS 8.4.1. When this method executed unit test execution crashes.

**Why unit test executing foo() function on iOS 8.x when it is marked for iOS 9.x?**

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
class func foo() {
    // Some code...
    if !TargetUtility.isRunningSimulator {
        // Crash happens when executed on iOS 8.4.1
        parameters[kSecAttrTokenID] = kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave
    }
}

// In the test file:

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func testFoo() {
    MyClass.foo()
}
```

Comment: I think that the testing framework does not honor `@available` for test definitions. Then it would just call `MyClass.foo()` which would make it crash. Could you try moving `@available` to the method body, e.g. `guard #available(iOS 9.0, *) else return`?

Comment: @Sulthan You are right. Could you post your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The testing framework probably does not honor `@available` for test definitions. That might be caused by the fact that XCUnit is an Objective-C framework and it essentially just grabs all the methods starting with `test...`

Moving the `@available` check to runtime should do the trick, e.g.:

```
guard #available(iOS 9.0, *) else {
   print("Test skipped")
   return
}
```

Unfortunately, XCUnit does not really have support for skipping tests.